# Use values in a list to extract specific rows from an excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have a spreadsheet where I'm trying to extract specific rows that contain a value from a list. The values checked are in the Task column of the spreadsheet. The spreadsheet has an unusual layout and is not friendly for parsing.

I converted the excel spreadsheet I need to parse into a JSON file so I could show it here in Stack Overflow since attachments are not possible.

I want to run the list of Task numbers against the Excel spreadsheet and create a new spreadsheet containing only the rows that contain the Task numbers from the task_number list.

Looking something like this:-

| Task | Description | A | B | C |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 130101 | something | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 131269 | something | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |

I've been trying to get this to work using Python and Pandas.

This is what I have so far:-

```
import pandas as pd

# the excel spreadsheet in JSON form
excel_sheet = '''{"Unnamed: 0.1":0,"Unnamed: 0":"Some sentence titling the page","Unnamed: 1":null,"Unnamed: 2":null,"Unnamed: 3":null,"Unnamed: 4":null,"Unnamed: 5":null},{"Unnamed: 0.1":1,"Unnamed: 0":null,"Unnamed: 1":null,"Unnamed: 2":null,"Unnamed: 3":null,"Unnamed: 4":null,"Unnamed: 5":null},{"Unnamed: 0.1":2,"Unnamed: 0":null,"Unnamed: 1":null,"Unnamed: 2":null,"Unnamed: 3":null,"Unnamed: 4":null,"Unnamed: 5":null},{"Unnamed: 0.1":3,"Unnamed: 0":"a thing:","Unnamed: 1":"sdftrhg","Unnamed: 2":null,"Unnamed: 3":null,"Unnamed: 4":null,"Unnamed: 5":null},{"Unnamed: 0.1":9,"Unnamed: 0":null,"Unnamed: 1":null,"Unnamed: 2":null,"Unnamed: 3":null,"Unnamed: 4":null,"Unnamed: 5":null},{"Unnamed: 0.1":10,"Unnamed: 0":"Task","Unnamed: 1":"Description","Unnamed: 2":"A","Unnamed: 3":"B","Unnamed: 4":"C","Unnamed: 5":null},{"Unnamed: 0.1":11,"Unnamed: 0":null,"Unnamed: 1":null,"Unnamed: 2":1,"Unnamed: 3":1,"Unnamed: 4":1,"Unnamed: 5":2.0},{"Unnamed: 0.1":12,"Unnamed: 0":"130","Unnamed: 1":null,"Unnamed: 2":null,"Unnamed: 3":null,"Unnamed: 4":null,"Unnamed: 5":null},{"Unnamed: 0.1":13,"Unnamed: 0":"130101","Unnamed: 1":"something","Unnamed: 2":1,"Unnamed: 3":2,"Unnamed: 4":3,"Unnamed: 5":4.0},{"Unnamed: 0.1":14,"Unnamed: 0":null,"Unnamed: 1":null,"Unnamed: 2":null,"Unnamed: 3":null,"Unnamed: 4":null,"Unnamed: 5":null},{"Unnamed: 0.1":15,"Unnamed: 0":null,"Unnamed: 1":"bam","Unnamed: 2":8,"Unnamed: 3":0,"Unnamed: 4":0,"Unnamed: 5":null},{"Unnamed: 0.1":16,"Unnamed: 0":null,"Unnamed: 1":null,"Unnamed: 2":null,"Unnamed: 3":null,"Unnamed: 4":null,"Unnamed: 5":null},{"Unnamed: 0.1":17,"Unnamed: 0":"131","Unnamed: 1":null,"Unnamed: 2":null,"Unnamed: 3":null,"Unnamed: 4":null,"Unnamed: 5":null},{"Unnamed: 0.1":18,"Unnamed: 0":"131269","Unnamed: 1":"something","Unnamed: 2":4,"Unnamed: 3":5,"Unnamed: 4":6,"Unnamed: 5":7.0},{"Unnamed: 0.1":43,"Unnamed: 0":null,"Unnamed: 1":null,"Unnamed: 2":null,"Unnamed: 3":null,"Unnamed: 4":null,"Unnamed: 5":null},{"Unnamed: 0.1":44,"Unnamed: 0":null,"Unnamed: 1":"bam","Unnamed: 2":8,"Unnamed: 3":0,"Unnamed: 4":0,"Unnamed: 5":null}'''

# convert JSON back to Excel
pd.read_json(excel_sheet , lines = True).to_excel("excel_sheet.xlsx")

# read in excel spreadsheet
excel_sheet = pd.read_excel("excel_sheet.xlsx")

task_number = [130101, 131269]

# create an empty dataframe with appropriate headings  
new_data = pd.DataFrame({'Task':[], 'Description':[], 'A':[], 'B':[], 'C':[], ' ':[]})

# search rows in dataframe and append rows containing values in task_number into 
# new_data dataframe (this is where it falls over). I use iloc to select the column by 
# index instead of by the Task name due to it not being at the top of the column. It doesn't work.
#for task in task_number:
#    new_data = new_data.append(excel_sheet[excel_sheet.iloc[:, 0] == task], ignore_index=True)

# This is another way as suggested by e-motta below, but it returns a empty dataframe
filtered_df = excel_sheet[excel_sheet.iloc[:, 0].isin(task_number)]
```

As my skill in parsing spreadsheets is bad to say the least I expect there's probably much better ways to do this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for taking the time to have a look at my problem.

Comment: please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I did. Did you read the explanation and example or do you just go around sticking in random comments for street cred?

Comment: I tried out your code and even tried to reconstruct the excel file, but before I invest more time in something that might or might not help you I'd prefer with the correct data.

Comment: Why don't you just filter the rows you need? `filtered_df = df[df.iloc[:, 0].isin(list_of_values)]`. Should be much faster than a for loop.

Comment: @NightTrain I've given everything I can. Some things are commercial in confidence.

Comment: @e-motta, thanks for that, I'm pretty sure I've tried something similar, but I'll give your suggestion a go and let you klnow.

Comment: @e-motta, the result I'm getting from your syggestion is an empty dataframe. I've updated my question providing a JSON interpretation of the excel file I'm trying to work with and simplified the code as well. Hopefully that makes it easier to find a solution for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reproducible example helps a lot in understanding the problems you're facing, namely:

1. You have extra columns at the start of the DataFrame. They either need to be removed if the data they contain is useless, or you need to consider them when indexing the filter (i.e., `df[df.iloc[:, 2].isin(task_numbers)].reset_index(drop=True)`). I chose to remove them in the example below.
2. The column with the task numbers is of type object and also contains data other than just numbers. You cannot convert the column to int, so you need to convert your `task_numbers` to a list (or an iterable) of str.

```py
df = pd.read_excel("excel_sheet.xlsx")

# Convert task numbers to str
task_numbers = map(str, [130101, 131269])

# Drop the first 2 columns
df = df.iloc[:, 2:]

# Filter the DataFrame and optionally reset the index
filtered_df = df[df.iloc[:, 0].isin(task_numbers)].reset_index(drop=True)

# Rename columns
filtered_df.columns = ["Task", "Description", "A", "B", "C", " "]
```

This is the result for the example:

```
     Task Description  A  B  C     
0  130101   something  1  2  3  4.0
1  131269   something  4  5  6  7.0
```